# How do I open the browser and do things automatic in one click?

Tags: c#

I started C# before 5 months ago and I thought to myself how could I open the browser and click on this and do CTRL+F and type something in and try to find the text that the computer will put in.

So I'm asking if it is possible?

Comment: Are you wanting to automate the clicking on things and entering text as if you were using the browser? It sounds like perhaps you want to automate the testing of a web application, in which case Selenium is a great place to start.

Comment: People here don't take too kindly to "give me teh codez!"

Answer (score 0):

To open a program with C#, you use **Process.Start("some.exe");** (and you'll need the proper parameters for it of course.

Now that you have a process, you can use **SendKeys()** to send keystrokes to your process.

Both of these are well documented on the internet, but for good measure:

[SendKeys documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Process.Start documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx)